# using firebase auth to login and met error endless waiting or PlatformException(sign_in_failed... ApiException 10

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I followed tutorial and tried to upload my flutter app to google play, by internal testing, logging is always unsuccessful, I am using firebase auth/gmail as auth tool.

The thing is I have generated some local keystore and when upload to google play console, I also used App Signing by Google Play Feature, therefore I have two different SHA-1, I have tried both, but both does not work, I had also used 'flutter clean' each time. But in IOS there is no such error.

Please let me know in my case firstly which SHA-1 I should use, and where is this error(endless waiting, sign_in_failed... ApiException 10) from, thanks!